# Construction of traingle when base, vertical angle and difference of base and one side is given

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles

When it is not possible to construct a triangle ABC, if BC = 6 cm, angle A = 50 degrees and difference in BC & AC is
a. 2.5 cm
b. 4 cm
c. 5 cm
d. 6.4 cm

P.S. can not use cosine rule, as the question is intended for school children...:(

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In a triangle, length of any edge should be larger than the difference of other two edges. Otherwise, it becomes a line. So the answer is D, but I do not know why the angle is given. Only reason I can think of is that since $A>0$ we know that it is not a line but it was triangle to begin with.</strike>

Sorry, misread the question.

<strike>I think all of the options are possible. At least, I was able to construct all of them in GeoGebra. But that may be wrong due to roundoff errors.</strike>

More rigorous, but definitely not elementary school level, explanation. Draw the line $BC$. Draw also the line $AC$ and a ray $AD$ such that the angle between $AC$ and $AD$ is $50$ degrees and $AD$ is directed in the general direction of the point $B$. If $AD$ intersects $BC$ at $B$, you are done. Otherwise, the intersection point is either before or after $B$. In that case, by continuously changing the angle $C$, or rotating $AC$ around $C$, we can continuously move the intersection point.

Since this explanation uses the continuity of the operation, it may not be possible to articulate in a way a kid would understand. However, I think that the question is wrong.

I will use law of sines but without actually calculating sines. Since $\angle BAC = 50>30$, $\sin(\angle BAC)>\sin(30)$ so $6/\sin(\angle BAC)<12$. But, necessarily $|AC|/\angle ABC = 6/\sin(\angle BAC)$. This is all good as long as $AC$ is shorter than $BC$. However, take $|AC|=12.4$. Then the minimum value $|AC|/\angle ABC$ can obtain is $12.4$ which is greater than $12$. So it is a contradiction. Correct answer is D.

Comment: How do you come about this reasoning without knowing either $AC$ or $AB$?

Comment: I also think question is wrong.. I used a bit different approach. instead of subtracting, I added 6.4 to 6, so it becomes 12.4. I first drew AC of 12.4 cm, then drew ray AD for angle of 60 degrees at A. Now will the line BC of 6 cm from B will intersect AD?

Comment: Sorry, I was being dumb. It is late where I am, but that is no excuse. Yes, $12.4$ cannot be the length of $AC$ and $-0.4$ is not a valid length. I am going to update my answer.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas Note that $\sin(50) \approx 0.766$, so $\frac{6}{\sin(50)} \approx 7.83$. Thus, from the sine law, the maximum value of $AC$ is about this. As such, using the interpretation the values given are the length of $AC$ minus that of $BC$, the maximum difference would be about $1.83$. This would mean *all* $4$ options are not valid, not just the last one, i.e., D.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I interpret the difference as $| |AC| - |BC| |$. So A, B and C are all valid as you can choose $|AC|<|BC|$. D is not valid because $|AC|$ can not be equal to $-0.4$ and by my argument, it cannot also be $12.4$. I avoided calculating exact $\sin$ value since this is a multiple choice test and it is likely that calculators are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The circumradius has been fixed with the given data, being equal to 
$$r = \frac{3}{\sin 50} = 3.92$$

If you think about it, all the possible points A will make an arc of a circle, and the chord AC will have maximum value when it is the diameter of the circle, i.e

$$ l(AC) = 2r = 7.83$$

Hence for the first three options, there will be a possible value of AC which is in (0,7.83) and satisfies the absolute difference, all except the last option